# Not able to use boundingclientrect properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hi I am trying to draw rectangle on a image which is drawn on canvas. So to look at it,the rectangle is seen on the image.

I have made a text box which takes numerical value to draw rectangle with 1,2,3.. partitions in it. If I am erasing the value the rectangle should disappear from the image but doing this even the image is also diapperaing with the same.

How to hold the image on the canvas. I am trying to use getBoundingClientRect for the same but doesnt know how to use the same in this regard.

```
function getStatus() {

        var layersCheckbox = document.getElementById("btnLAYER");
        var patches = document.getElementById('txtPatchCount');
        var roiCheckbox = document.getElementById("btnROI");
         var metricsCheckbox = document.getElementById("btnMetrics");

        bSetROI = roiCheckbox.checked;
         bSetMetrics = metricsCheckbox.checked;
        bSetLayers = layersCheckbox.checked;
        patchCount = patches.value;

        if (!bSetROI || !patchCount ) {
            patchCount = 0;

        }
}


$(function(){

  $("#txtPatchCount").keyup(function () 

        {
                getStatus();

                // clear the canvas
                o2DContext.clearRect(0, 0, oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height);
                 oCanvas.getBoundingClientRect();  
                // redraw all previously saved line-pairs and roi
                for (var i = 0; i < layers_array.length; i++) {
                    var layer5 = layers_array[i];
                    if (layer5.patchCount > 0) {
                        layer5.patchCount = patchCount;
                    }
                    draw(layer5);
                }
           }
  );
});
```

Comment: Or is there any other method to get hold of the image on the screen.

Comment: getBoundingClientRect is a method which has the only purpose to return... the bounding client rect. You can then use the top and left property of this rect to adjust coordinates (typically when reading clientX/Y in mouse/touch event). Just calling getBoundingClientRect has no magical effect ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `getBoundingClientRect()` method only returns the current absolute position and dimension of an *element* (being a canvas, image or any other element).

Just calling it does nothing - it returns an object with some properties you can read and the use for something:

```
var rectangle = element.getBoundingClientRect();

console.log(rectangle.left, rectangle.top, rectangle.width, rectangle.height)
```

and there is also `right` and `bottom` for convenience. Note that padding and border is included if those are applied.

If you clear the canvas you will need to redraw everything on it as canvas is a passive bitmap only holding pixels with whatever was draw on it including the image (you are not showing the code of your `draw()` method so excuse me for being generic here and it's not clear how you intend to use this method in this regard).

(If your image covers the entire canvas you don't event need to clear it, just redraw the image).

Comment: Thanks, I figured out the problem :)

Comment: @Coder25 please share with us :) You can answer your own question.

Comment: I was not able to answer my won question but here's the solution.After clearing the canvas, I again loaded the images so only the rectangle will disappear after clearing the text box but the image will be intact there. 

       var oSelect = document.getElementById("ImageList");

       changeCanvasImage(oSelect[oSelect.selectedIndex].value);